# this function cause browser crash

Tags: javascript

I have written a function that i want to detect the language of the text based on utf-8 encoding.Actualy this function determines the input argumant is english or not.The function work correctly in javascript console but when I use it in a loop ,the browser crashes.

```
//titles.lenght=>90


function is_eng(title) {
var A = 65;
var z = 122;
title = title.toString();
var eng_chars = 0;
var non_eng_chars = 0;
for (i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
    var c = title.charCodeAt(i);
    if (c > A && c < z) {
        eng_chars += 1;
    } else {
        non_eng_chars += 1;
    }
}
if (eng_chars > non_eng_chars) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the browser crashes? It throws a JS exception? Or causes the whole browser process to stop?

Comment: Can you share your loop code? maybe you are using i too many times.

Comment: Why are your parsing `title` to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the keyword `var` before `i=0`, otherwise `i` is a global variable. If you use `i` for the external loop, you have an endless loop.